# AddEventListener - Undefined method when using external function

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have some code like this:

```
  addMarkerListener(){
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (event) => (this.handleMarkerListenerClick(event)));
  }

  handleMarkerListenerClick(event){
    let target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a" && target.className.startsWith("ver-mais-unidade")){
      this.onViewUnidade();
    }
  }
```

It works pretty fine, but I need to remove that listener later, so I would have to call my handler like this:

```
  addMarkerListener(){
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', this.handleMarkerListenerClick);
  }

  handleMarkerListenerClick(event){
    let target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a" && target.className.startsWith("ver-mais-unidade")){
      this.onViewUnidade();
    }
  }
```

The problem is, with that second code, I got "this.onViewUnidade" is undefined. `onViewUnidade` is a function in my component and works nice on the first case. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: In your constructor, say `this.handleMarkerListenerClick = this.handleMarkerListenerClick.bind(this);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [instance function](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript#use-instance-functions)

```
handleMarkerListenerClick = (event) => {
```

or in constructor:

```
this.handleMarkerListenerClick = this.handleMarkerListenerClick.bind(this);
```

But would be better to use angular way like

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
handleMarkerListenerClick(e) { ... }
```

or

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
...
this.listenFunc = renderer.listen(document.body, 'click', (e) => {
   ...
});
...
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.listenFunc();
}
```

Comment: tried for first the constructor solution and worked like a charm. Thanks so much!